# Numeric TextBox in C# - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, numbers

i want to create a textbox in WPF that only accept numbers...
i've reaserched and people say to use keypress event or masked textbox, but they are in windows forms...

Answer (score 33):

For WPF:

```
private void textBox1_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsDigit(e.Text, e.Text.Length - 1))
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

For Windows Forms:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) )
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: be careful with copy pasting into your box, won't be controlled by such a code

Comment: Easy solve Maciek and J3soon appreciated