# How to make a textbox that only accepts number and decimal points in c#?

Tags: c#

How to make a textbox that only accepts number and decimal points in c# ?

looking for something very simple if anyone knows please help !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505008/numeric-textbox-in-c-sharp-wpf

Comment: Is this for winforms/ wpf or MVC/ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

try this code...

```html
 if (!(char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back || e.KeyChar == '.'))
            { e.Handled = true; }
            TextBox txtDecimal = sender as TextBox;
            if (e.KeyChar == '.' && txtDecimal.Text.Contains("."))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a [Masked TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx). Create one, and put this [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) into the Mask section: `^(\d+)?+([\.]{1})?+([\d]{1,2})?$`